# UnityContainer new instances

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a sample application with the following views:

1. MainWindow
2. NewCustomer
3. CustomerStep1
4. CustomerStep2
5. Home

I use unity to register Types in the App.xaml.cs.

I have constructor parameters as follows:

MainWindow(NewCustomer, Home)

NewCustomer(CustomerStep1, CustomerStep2)

The MainWindow the following xaml

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
        <Button Content="Home" Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button Content="New Customer" Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Width="100" Click="Button1_Click" />
    </ToolBar>
    <ContentControl x:Name="mainRegion" />
</DockPanel>
```

I have the viewmodels for each of them and all are working fine.

The problem I have is when I click New Customer and enter information in step 1 and step 2 and then I click on Home and click again on New Customer the data is not cleared. How do I clear the data from these objects.

Code behind of MainWindow I use:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainRegion.Content = null;
        mainRegion.Content = _homeView;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainRegion.Content = null;
        mainRegion.Content = _newCustomerView;
    }
```

If I move away from the New Customer View and click on New Customer again, I would expect the form to be new. But it is not happening.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was able to clear the data if I passed my container to the MainWindow and resolve the HomeView and NewCustomerView using the the container.Resolve<>. I am not sure if it is a good practice to pass the container around.

Answer (score 0):

How are you types registered?, what lifetime manager did you use?

This might also help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: I am using the default (Not specifying any) which I see is TransientLifetimeManager. The problem I see is MainWindow is still alive and that's why it does not resolve again. It gives me the same object with the values previously entered. If I pass the Container to MainWindow and do a resolve then it clears it. Currently I am not happy with the solution. In the meantime I am delving into the Prism samples for UI composition and Navigation to understand how the region managers and views work.

Comment: @user1549435 ok, you seem to know what your doing!.. Id highly recommend PRISM, its a fantastic and very powerful toolkit

Comment: Thanks for your advise and the link. It is a lot to comprehend in PRISM as I see them now. Hopefully I will figure out :)